# Excel set cell list value to cell above based on condition

Tags: excel-2016

In Excel column D is of a list type.  Cell D3 is correctly populated according to the list.  When A4 is not null D4 must be equal to D3.  This works fine when A4 is not null, however when A4 is blank I get a validation error.  The idea is when I do not have a value in A4 nothing should happen in D4, i.e. D4 should also remain blank.

I have tried

```
=if(A4<>"",D3,"")
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the ISBLANK function (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IS-functions-0f2d7971-6019-40a0-a171-f2d869135665) instead of comparing to a String?

Comment: It did work, thank you.  However, the formula needs to be added in the correct order.  First put in a value in A4, then update the formula.  When A4 is cleared it will work.  But never the less - it works.